# Tweak anchor points and direction of zig zags for TikZ digram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have an example here for a database diagram:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{crow's foot}{crow's foot}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}%
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+.5\pgflinewidth}%
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.5pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.25\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
  \pgfsetmiterjoin%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-6\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-6\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{6\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
  \pgfusepathqstroke%
}

\tikzset{
    entity/.code={
        \tikzset{
            label=above:#1,
            name=#1,
            inner sep=0pt,
            every entity/.try,
            fill=white,
            general shadow={
                shadow xshift=0.0625in,
                shadow yshift=-0.0625in,
                opacity=0.5,
                fill=black!50
            }
        }%
        \def\entityname{#1}%
    },
    entity anchor/.style={matrix anchor=#1.center},
    every entity/.style={
            draw,
    },
    every property/.style={
        inner xsep=0.25cm, inner ysep=0.125cm, anchor=west, text width=1.45in
    },
    zig zag to/.style={
        to path={(\tikztostart) -| ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) |- (\tikztotarget)}
    },
    zig zag to/.default=0.5,
    one to many/.style={
        -crow's foot, zig zag to
    },
    many to one/.style={
        crow's foot-, zig zag to
    },
    many to many/.style={
        crow's foot-crow's foot, zig zag to
    }
}

\def\property#1{\node[name=\entityname-#1, every property/.try]{#1};}
\def\properties{\begingroup\catcode`\_=11\relax\processproperties}
\def\processproperties#1{\endgroup%
    \def\propertycode{}%
    \foreach \p in {#1}{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\propertycode%
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\propertycode\expandafter\property\expandafter{\p}\\}%
    }%
    \propertycode%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\ttfamily}, node distance=1in]

\matrix [entity=Msp\string_Support\string_Period] {
    \properties{
        spe_refno,   
        spe_peo_refno,
        spe_spcs_refno,
        spe_start,
        spe_expected_end,
        (etc)
    }
};

\matrix [entity=People, 
         right=3cm of Msp\string_Support\string_Period-spe_refno, 
         entity anchor=People-peo_refno] {
    \properties{
        peo_refno,        
        peo_surname, 
        peo_dob,
        peo_hrv_ethnic,
        (etc)
    }
};

\matrix [entity=Sp\string_Contracted\string_Services, 
         below left =4.5cm and -1cm of Msp\string_Support\string_Period-spe_refno, 
         entity anchor=Sp\string_Contracted\string_Services-spcs_spcn_contract_id] {
    \properties{
        spcs_spcn_contract_id,   
        exp_org_name,
        exp_hrv_exp_type,
        (etc)
    }
};

\matrix [entity=Msp\string_Referral,
         below right =4cm and -1cm of People-peo_refno,
         entity anchor=Msp\string_Referral-ref_peo_refno] {
    \properties{
        ref_peo_refno,   
        ref_exp_refno,
        ref_spcs_refno,     
        ref_type, 
        ref_received_by,
        ref_reject_date,
        (etc)
    }
};

\matrix [entity=Hou\string_Ref\string_Values, 
         right=4cm of People-peo_refno, 
         entity anchor=Hou\string_Ref\string_Values-hrv_code] {
    \properties{
        hrv_code,   
        hrv_hrd_domain,
        hrv_name,
        (etc)
    }
};

\matrix [entity=Msp\string_External\string_Parties, 
         below right=4cm and 7.5cm of Msp\string_Referral-ref_exp_refno, 
         entity anchor=Msp\string_Referral-ref_exp_refno] {
    \properties{
        exp_refno,   
        exp_org_name,
        exp_hrv_exp_type,
        (etc)
    }
};

\draw [many to one] (Msp\string_Support\string_Period-spe_refno)   to (People-peo_refno);
\draw [many to one] (Msp\string_Support\string_Period-spe_spcs_refno)  to (Sp\string_Contracted\string_Services-spcs_spcn_contract_id);
\draw [many to one] (People-peo_refno)   to (Msp\string_Referral-ref_peo_refno);
\draw [many to one] (Msp\string_Referral-ref_spcs_refno)   to (Sp\string_Contracted\string_Services-spcs_spcn_contract_id);
\draw [many to one] (Msp\string_Referral-ref_exp_refno)   to (Msp_External_Parties-exp_refno);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That gives me this output:

[image]

I would like the zig zags to behave gracefully and avoid overlapping with other shapes or other zig zags.

That is to say, the left hand side zig zag should be anchored to the left side of the Sp_Contracted_Services table and to the left side of the Msp_Support_Period table. In addition, the zig zag in the centre should anchor to the right side of People and the right side of Msp_Referral.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is easy or even possible to generalize the `zigzag` and `many to one` styles in such a way that they automatically avoid crossing the nodes. However, it is easy enough to tweak the edges by hand.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{crow's foot}{crow's foot}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}%
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+.5\pgflinewidth}%
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.5pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.25\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
  \pgfsetmiterjoin%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-6\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-6\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{6\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
  \pgfusepathqstroke%
}

\tikzset{
    entity/.code={
        \tikzset{
            label=above:#1,
            name=#1,
            inner sep=0pt,
            every entity/.try,
            fill=white,
            general shadow={
                shadow xshift=0.0625in,
                shadow yshift=-0.0625in,
                opacity=0.5,
                fill=black!50
            }
        }%
        \def\entityname{#1}%
    },
    entity anchor/.style={matrix anchor=#1.center},
    every entity/.style={
            draw,
    },
    every property/.style={
        inner xsep=0.25cm, inner ysep=0.125cm, anchor=west, text width=1.45in
    },
    zig zag to/.style={
        to path={(\tikztostart) -| ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) |- (\tikztotarget)}
    },
    zig zag to/.default=0.5,
    one to many/.style={
        -crow's foot, zig zag to
    },
    many to one/.style={
        crow's foot-, zig zag to
    },
    many to many/.style={
        crow's foot-crow's foot, zig zag to
    }
}

\def\property#1{\node[name=\entityname-#1, every property/.try]{#1};}
\def\properties{\begingroup\catcode`\_=11\relax\processproperties}
\def\processproperties#1{\endgroup%
    \def\propertycode{}%
    \foreach \p in {#1}{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\propertycode%
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\propertycode\expandafter\property\expandafter{\p}\\}%
    }%
    \propertycode%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\ttfamily}, node distance=1in]

\matrix [entity=Msp\string_Support\string_Period] {
    \properties{
        spe_refno,   
        spe_peo_refno,
        spe_spcs_refno,
        spe_start,
        spe_expected_end,
        (etc)
    }
};

\matrix [entity=People, 
         right=3cm of Msp\string_Support\string_Period-spe_refno, 
         entity anchor=People-peo_refno] {
    \properties{
        peo_refno,        
        peo_surname, 
        peo_dob,
        peo_hrv_ethnic,
        (etc)
    }
};

\matrix [entity=Sp\string_Contracted\string_Services, 
         below left =4.5cm and -1cm of Msp\string_Support\string_Period-spe_refno, 
         entity anchor=Sp\string_Contracted\string_Services-spcs_spcn_contract_id] {
    \properties{
        spcs_spcn_contract_id,   
        exp_org_name,
        exp_hrv_exp_type,
        (etc)
    }
};

\matrix [entity=Msp\string_Referral,
         below right =4cm and -1cm of People-peo_refno,
         entity anchor=Msp\string_Referral-ref_peo_refno] {
    \properties{
        ref_peo_refno,   
        ref_exp_refno,
        ref_spcs_refno,     
        ref_type, 
        ref_received_by,
        ref_reject_date,
        (etc)
    }
};

\matrix [entity=Hou\string_Ref\string_Values, 
         right=4cm of People-peo_refno, 
         entity anchor=Hou\string_Ref\string_Values-hrv_code] {
    \properties{
        hrv_code,   
        hrv_hrd_domain,
        hrv_name,
        (etc)
    }
};

\matrix [entity=Msp\string_External\string_Parties, 
         below right=4cm and 7.5cm of Msp\string_Referral-ref_exp_refno, 
         entity anchor=Msp\string_Referral-ref_exp_refno] {
    \properties{
        exp_refno,   
        exp_org_name,
        exp_hrv_exp_type,
        (etc)
    }
};

\draw [many to one] (Msp\string_Support\string_Period-spe_refno)   to (People-peo_refno);
\draw [crow's foot-] (Msp\string_Support\string_Period-spe_spcs_refno.west)  
-- ++(-1.5cm,0) |-
(Sp\string_Contracted\string_Services-spcs_spcn_contract_id.west);
\draw [crow's foot-] (People-peo_refno.east)   -- ++(0.5cm,0) 
-- ++(0,-3.2cm) --++(-4cm,0)
|- (Msp\string_Referral-ref_peo_refno);
\draw [many to one] (Msp\string_Referral-ref_spcs_refno)   to (Sp\string_Contracted\string_Services-spcs_spcn_contract_id);
\draw [many to one] (Msp\string_Referral-ref_exp_refno)   to (Msp_External_Parties-exp_refno);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I now know that it is pretty easy to manually tweak the lines. I'm coming at TikZ from the wrong direction (not learning the fundamentals) so your answer helps a lot. :)